# sqlschemacompare on Visual studio 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, wpf

When I try to compare my database project to an existing database it displays the following error:

> **The write operation failed. You must first acquire write access from DataSchemaModelController. E:\SRC SF\LIBRIDB\TePuna.scmp**

Sql Server Version is 2012 Dev Edition

This happened after I reinstalled visual studio and sql server.

I have also installed SQL Server Data Tools 2012.

I searched with the same error on google but found nothing.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error when I upgraded a set of DevExpress controls. I shutdown the IDE and restarted. Everything worked fine afterwards.

Comment: It's amazing how many problems can be fixed in this way.  Most of my SO reputation comes from suggesting that people close and re-open Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Update - if you double-click on the new installer and then select "Repair" it will install correctly and you can do schema compares.  The SSDT installer for VS2012 does not suffer from this problem - it seems to be confined to the VS2010 installer

Comment: This actually happened to me on VS2012, and a repair on the installation resolved it. Maybe it has to do with how it's installed - I clicked the Update button from the Extensions and Updates dialog under Tools. Since it never warned about VS being open, I continued working in VS while it downloaded and installed. The installer did restart VS2012, but apparently not at the right time, seems it failed to register something as a result.